# Showing results of a database query inside Navigation Tab

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, xampp

I want to show the results of a database query inside the navigation tab of the home page. How do I call the $results variable inside the posts tab of the home page (the last code block). Thanks

PostController.php

```
class NoteController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $posts = DB::select(....);
return view('posts.index',['results' => $posts]);
}
```

The post index blade

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    @foreach($results as $notes)
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          {{$notes->note}}
        </div>
      </div>
    @endforeach
  </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

The home index file

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#posts">Posts</a></li>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="posts" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to use save function in multiple views you can use `AppServiceProvider.php` file in App->Providers. there you can make composer view to pass variables in all your views look at sample below:

```
View::composer('*', function ($view) {
  $ads = Ad::all();
  foreach($ads as $ad){
    $customJs = $ad->js;
    $customCss = $ad->css;
  }
  $view->with('customJs', $customJs);
  $view->with('customCss', $customCss);
});
```

by this sample now I have ability of using `$customJs` and `$customCss` in any view i want.

Hope it helps.